# CentOS qt-creator when executing step qmake

Tags: qt, qt-creator, centos7

I'm new at qt, and that's my first day with qt-creator, I just built a blank project try to compile, then wrong message came up.
Here is my config file :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using the Qt and Qt Creator provided by CentOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The make step says: "No compiler set in kit". Please install a compiler (gcc or clang both work on Linux) and restart Qt Creator.

If the restart does not help: Go to Tools>Options>Build & Run>Toolchains and check that your compilers are detected. Then hit the "Apply" button and switch to the "Kits" tab of the options window.

Make sure the expected compiler is listed in the kit (after selecting the "Desktop" kit. Make sure no warnings/errors are shown in front of the kit. If there are any: Hover the kit with your mouse and check the tooltip for details.

Hope this helps:-)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was elsewhere. I did have GCC installed (in Ubuntu), but I didn't have **G++** (which is the GCC component for building **C++** code). I installed G++, restarted Qt Creator and that fixed it.